# ARR Requests Not Properly Routing to Server Farm

Tags: iis, arr, windows-server-2019

I have installed ARR on my Windows 2019 server via the IIS Platform Installer and configured it by adding a server farm and adding a single server to it.

I can ping the server and ARR shows it is online.  The issue is, when I submit a request from my local PC, it seems to hit the ARR server but it never hits the server farm.  The browser returns **404 Not Found**.

On the ARR server, if I create a request to "controlcenter.mydomain.com" and view the logs in `C:\iislogs\www\HTTPERR` I see this error:

```
2020-10-30 19:14:54 [my local computer IP address] 53391 [my ARR server IP address] 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / - 404 - NotFound -
```

The sites on my webfarm server are "controlcenter.mydomain.com" and "api.mydomain.com."  Do I need to create special rewrite rules for these sub domains?  I cannot seem to tell from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing).

**How can I find out why the request is not being properly routed from the ARR server to the server I've added to my server farm (shown below)?**

[image]

When I tried to reset runtime statistics on the Monitoring and Management page, it says, "The operation could not be completed because the worker process has stopped."

[image]

[image]

The health test with URL "http://controlcenter.mydomain.com" succeeds also.

Comment: You can see the availability and health status in the image, all of them are unknown. It means ARR cannot connect to server normally. It is necessary to check the status of server again. If the server is normally, availability should be available and health status is healthy. You can check the connection through verifying URL test in Health Test.

Comment: I ran the health test and it returned success.  When I tried to reset runtime statistics on the Monitoring and Management page, it says, "The operation could not be completed because the worker process has stopped."  The sites on my webfarm server are "controlcenter.mydomain.com" and "api.mydomain.com."  Do I need to do any special rewriting?  Maybe that's why it's not working correctly?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BruceZhang I've added more details to the original question.  Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use ARR, you must first make sure to create a site bound to your domain, and then ARR can forward requests for that domain to the server farm.

In order to solve the problem of stopping the work process, there are the following methods.

- Setting Ping Enabled to False stops IIS from checking whether the worker process is still running and keeps the worker process alive until you stop your debugged process. Setting Ping Maximum Response Time to a large value allows IIS to continue monitoring the worker process. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-web-site-worker-process-has-been-terminated-by-iis?view=vs-2019#to-configure-iis-7-to-allow-the-worker-process-to-continue).
- Run this command from the elevated command prompt on the controller machine.

`net stop webfarmservice & cd /d "%programfiles%\iis\Microsoft Web Farm Framework" & mkdir    extensions & move WFFExtension.dll extensions & net start webfarmservice`

When I tested in my environment and killed the w3wp.exe, health test returned success but status of servers were unknow. This command solved the issue.

- Delete the server farms and restart the IIS, then re-create server farms and add servers.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed info!  When you say, "create a site bound to your domain," I want to clarify:  I have specified a binding on my IIS site for `controlcenter.mydomain.com`.  The DNS for `controlcenter.mydomain.com` currently points to the existing load balancer.  If my testing goes well with ARR, I will eventually update the DNS to point to the ARR server instead of the existing load balancer (which is reaching end of support soon).  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Also, when I try to run the command, it says, "The service name is invalid."  This is probably because the `webfarmservice` doesn't exist on my Window Server 2019 machine.  I came across this post https://forums.iis.net/t/1228714.aspx?Windows+Server+2016+install+Microsoft+Web+Farm+Framework+issue but the download links for the Web Farm Framework .msi don't seem to work anymore: 
 https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-farm-framework

Comment: There is a simple way to restart w3wp.exe, just create a site and visit it. For the 404 error you encountered at the beginning, I suggest you enable FailRequestTracing. First check the records on the ARR server to find the forwarded backend server, and then check how the request is executed on the backend server. I think the problem is likely to be a problem with the back-end server. If it is a problem with the ARR server, a 50x status code should be displayed.

Comment: Thank you!  It is working now!  I didn't realize this, but on the ARR server itself, I needed to have the "Default Web Site" running.  Thanks for your help with this!